# How do I get the specific value from configuration in IIS 8.0 (and above) using appcmd?

Tags: windows, iis, iis-8, appcmd

I am using IIS 8.5 and I need a getter for a specific property from configuration.

For example, in order to set `connectionTimeout` property I am using the following syntax :

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /siteDefaults.limits.connectionTimeout:"00:04:00" /commit:apphost
```

but when I am trying to read the proprety by the following command:

```
appcmd.exe list config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /siteDefaults.limits.connectionTimeout
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR ( message:The attribute "siteDefaults.limits.connectionTimeout"
>   is not supported in the current command usage. )

and from what I tried so far it seems that list config command can give me only the section level and not further.

Is there any other way to get a specific property using appcmd?

Comment: someone who can help?

Answer (score 1):

If Powershell is an acceptable alternative for you, then you can use the `WebAdministration` Powersell module to get the timeout. Here is a simple script :

```ps
#import WebAdministration to access IIS configuration
Import-Module WebAdministration

#declare variables containing your filters
$pspath = "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"
$filter = "system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults/limits"
$name   = "connectionTimeout"

#Read timeout from IIS
$res = Get-WebConfigurationProperty -name $name -filter $filter -pspath $pspath 

#Format & write output
Write-Host "Timeout (in seconds): " $res.Value.TotalSeconds -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

You probably need to run it as admin.

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get this using /text:

```
appcmd.exe list config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /text:siteDefaults.limits.connectionTimeout
```

if you want to get all possible options for /text: use the following code:

```
appcmd.exe list config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /text:?
```